# Wordpress - Menu links and dropdown does not work in frontpage home

Tags: wordpress

When we load site www.cligest.com made with WordPress the menu links and the dropdown options on the web initial page, the frontpage ("home") don't work. They just work in all other pages except "home".

I've tried 15 different solutions, with no luck.

Comment: can you what had been tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following css:

```
nav ul.main-menu {

    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Hari! It worked like a charm! After two years of development our site has finnaly gone live thanks to your finnal tip! :D

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you have a `div` on top of the menu. It only happens on the homepage because that div or `.homepage-section` only exists on the homepage.

Try adding this to your CSS sheet and see if it makes any difference. It should bring your menu on top.

```
.main-menu {z-index: 2}
```